# How can I create another Block for my attributes like the dropdown in the picture? (Product page)

Tags: attributes

I need to add a dropdown as the one in the image. The current dropdown, shown in the image, contains some of my attributes. However, I need to add an additional dropdown for other attributes which is identical to the one in the image.

Can someone help?

Please let me know if you need additional information. This is my first question and I'm new to using Magento :)

[image: Div]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stack exchange, and to Magento ! From what I can see of the code, it seems that there is a theme applied, or that the code has already been modfied a lot. If you have a theme, can you please give the name ? Some people might know it and help you with its specific behavior.

Comment: Thank you for respondent. The theme is Hyvä.